# Simple android app crash after start

Tags: android, xml, crash

I tried to make a simple android app, that will trigger webserver to open the gate, everything worked just fine till I made some design (not java) changes. Now I cant even start the app properly.

Please take a look and tell me if you have any ideas. It tried the apk @ Galaxy S3 and Note 3

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="wstrends.brana" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="WS trends Gatekeeper"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="WS trends Gatekeeper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Otevřít bránu"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Pro prokračování vložte heslo"
        android:id="@+id/upper"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:password="false"
        android:textColor="#bc000000" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upper"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:hint="Heslo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#CA0700</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the logcat ?

Comment: Post logcat. Provide java code too.

Comment: This is my first app so I didnt know that there is any logcat tool, so now I see it says "RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wstrends.brana/wstrends.brana.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." .. now I know what I did wrong, thanks guys ;).. for logcat tip

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `styles.xml` to the following. The theme must be a descendant of `Theme.AppCompat`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> <!-- For support lib compat -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#CA0700</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, see my solution which I found out

Comment: Tried this solution and I came up with error:
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: @Jkr I assumed you were on API 21 (Lollipop) by the error message, but if you are not then you will not have that resource. My mistake.

Comment: I made it compatible with ICS, I dont rly know If everyone who will use it has Lollipop and higher. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: @Jkr Well if you decide to go that route, you can use the [v7-support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) to maintain backwards compatibility and also gain many new Lollipop features.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

no changes in styles.xml whatsoever, but a little change in MainActivity.java fixed this

From **public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity** to **public class MainActivity extends Activity**